# Why doesn't Python include number of digits I specify after the decimal point when rounding?

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

For example,

```
a = 5 * 6.2
print (round(a, 2)
```

The output is 31.0. I would have expected 31.00.

```
b = 2.3 * 3.2
print (round(b, 3))
```

The output is 7.36. I would have expected 7.360.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are confusing rounding with formatting. Rounding produces a new `float` object with the rounded value, which is still going to print the same way as any other float:

```
>>> print(31.00)
31.0
```

Use the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) if you need to produce a *string* with a specific number of decimals:

```
>>> print(format(31.0, '.2f'))
31.00
```

See the [*Format Specification Mini-Language*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) section for what options you have available.

If the value is part of a larger string, you can use the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to embed values into a string template, using the same formatting specifications:

```
>>> a = 5 * 6.2
>>> print('The value of "a" is {:.2f}'.format(a))
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean that using print(format(31.0, '.2f')) produces a string? It is no longer a float?

Comment: @tochau: `format()` produces a string, using the given specification, from the floating point value. `print()` then outputs that string to your console or terminal.

Answer (score 6):

Python always prints at least one digit after the decimal point so you can tell the difference between integers and floats.

The `round()` function merely rounds the number to the specified number of decimal places. It does not control how it is printed. 7.36 and 7.360 are the same number, so the shorter is printed.

To control the printing, you can use formatting.  For example:

```
print(".3f" % b)
```

Answer (score 5):

Python does round to 3 decimal places. It is the printing that cuts additional zeros. Try something like `print("%.3f" % number)`